# Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Assume arrivals occur according to a Poisson process with average 7 per hour. What’s the probability exactly two customers arrive in the two hour period of time between:

1pm to 2pm and 3 to 4pm

I have this but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect $P(Y=2) = 2\left(\frac{14^2}{2!} \times e^{-14}\right)$

Comment: There should not be a $2$ in front.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so is it just (14^2/2! * e^-14)?

Comment: Yes, the fact that the $2$ hour period is split makes no difference, the number of arrivals has Poisson distribution parameter $\lambda=14$, probability is $e^{-14}\frac{14^2}{2!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the following scenarios are counted:

- two customers in 1pm to 2pm slot, none in the other slot
- no customers arrive in 1pm to 2pm slot, two arrive in 3pm to 4pm slot
- one customer in 1pm to 2pm slot, one customer in the other slot

These scenarios are mutually exclusive, so the probability is:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(\text{exactly two})&=\frac{\Gamma^2 e^{-\Gamma}}{2!}\frac{\Gamma^0 e^{-\Gamma}}{0!}+\frac{\Gamma^0 e^{-\Gamma}}{0!}\frac{\Gamma^2 e^{-\Gamma}}{2!}+\frac{\Gamma^1 e^{-\Gamma}}{1!}\frac{\Gamma^1 e^{-\Gamma}}{1!} \\[2ex]
&=(\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}+1)\Gamma^2 e^{-2\Gamma} \\[2ex]
&=2\Gamma^2 e^{-2\Gamma} \\[2ex]
&=2\times7^2 e^{-14}
\end{align}$$

because there are $\Gamma=7$ expected arrivals per hour.

If my interpretation of the question is correct, your answer is off by a factor of 2.

---

Since Poissonian events are independent of each other and do not depend on when timing intervals start, the split periods can be treated as a single continuous two hour period, as André Nicolas does.

Comment: Your answer is $\dfrac{14^2 e^{-14}}{2!}$, as one might expect.  The sum of two independent Poisson random variables also has a Poisson distribution, with mean equal to the sum of the two original means